# .net core WebAPI running cli commands

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, visual-studio, command-line-interface

I'm creating a WebApi in .net core 5, and I wanted it to call some [CLI commands](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/dotnet-new) to create projects inside a solution that will be dynamically created. And if possible, I would like to receive the return of CLI commands within .net. Is it possible to do this?

I will have a javascript and HTML interface that will call this API (to create projects dynamically) and show the result of the creation (CLI return)

[image]

Comment: I searched a lot of information and found no relevant information. I am afraid it is difficult to implement in .net core WebAPI

Answer (score 1):

I think this example will be useful

```
    [HttpGet("{name}")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Create(string name)
    {
        string outputText = string.Empty;
        var standardError = string.Empty;

        try
        {
            using (Process process = new Process())
            {
                process.StartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo
                {
                    FileName = "dotnet",
                    Arguments = @$"new sln -o {name}",
                    WorkingDirectory = @"C:\projects",//the file must exist
                    RedirectStandardOutput = true,
                    RedirectStandardError = true,
                    UseShellExecute = false,
                    CreateNoWindow = false,
                };

                process.Start();
                outputText = process.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
                outputText = outputText.Replace(Environment.NewLine, string.Empty);
                standardError = process.StandardError.ReadToEnd();
                process.WaitForExit();
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

        }
        return Ok(outputText + standardError);
    }
```